# Adding loggers for root in connecting python modules

Tags: python, logging, config, python-logging

We have a ready-made project with built-in logging. Logs are accepted by logger_root, but we also have plug-ins that are located in other directories. To process them, we need to add individual loggers in the configuration files. We have a lot of such modules. How can we set up redirection to rootlogger by changing only the basic logging configuration?
**Project file structure:**

```
project/
├─ libs/
│  ├─ module1/
│  │  └─ src/
│  │     └─ module1/
│  │        └─ file_with_log.py
│  ├─ module2/
│  └─ .../
├─ apps/
│  ├─ module3/
│  ├─ module4/
│  └─ .../
└─ core_app/
   └─ src/
      └─ core_app/
         └─ init_root_logger.py
```

In all modules, logging is initialized via:
`LOG=logging.getLogger(__name__)`

How do we get rid of the description of a bunch of loggers, and reduce everything to logger_root?

```
[loggers]
keys=root,module1,module2,...

[handlers]
 keys=error,info,warn,stderr

[formatters]
  keys=default

[logger_root]
  level=INFO
  handlers=error,info,warn

[logger_module1]
  level=INFO
  handlers=error,info,warn
  qualname=module1

[logger_module2]
  level=INFO
  handlers=error,info,warn
  propogate=0
  qualname=module2.folder.module
...

...
[handler_error]
  class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
  level=ERROR
  formatter=default
  args=('%LOG_DIR%/project.ERROR', 'a+', 1000000, 5)

[handler_info]
  class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
  level=INFO
  formatter=default
  args=('%LOG_DIR%/project.INFO', 'a+', 1000000, 5)

[handler_warn]
  class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
  level=WARNING
  formatter=default
  args=('%LOG_DIR%/project.WARNING', 'a+', 1000000, 5)
[formatter_default]
  class=desktop.log.formatter.Formatter
  format=[%(asctime)s] %(module)-12s str-%(lineno)-4d %(levelname)-8s %(message)s
```

We cannot move the initialization of rootlogger.